# mutiple insert Query Works in phpmyadmin but does not work in php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project on godaddy shared hosting.  I am able to run the following query in phpmyadmin successfully: (this is the exact output of the php script)

```
INSERT INTO payments_facebook(`adset`,`amount`,`date`,`oid` ) VALUES ('6023516764849','3.27','2015-07-25','58'); 
INSERT INTO payments_facebook(`adset`,`amount`,`date`,`oid` ) VALUES ('6023315002249','200','2015-07-25','53'); 
INSERT INTO payments_facebook(`adset`,`amount`,`date`,`oid` ) VALUES ('6023221698649','3.43','2015-07-25','52')
```

I am using the old mysql_query function to insert the data. When I run this query through PHP I get a following error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO payments_facebook(`adset`,`amount`,`date`,`oid` ) VALUES ('602331500' at line 1
```

but when I run the same query in phpmyadmin it works perfectly.

Here is the structure of the mysql table:

- id   int(100):
- date varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci
- oid  int(50)
- amount   double
- adset    varchar(200) latin1_swedish_ci

Hopefully someone can help me figure this out, I am not sure if this is a godaddy server limitation or if I have an error in my DB or syntax.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: per the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php `mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.`

Comment: Thank you I was not aware or this limitation. I need to stop using this depreciated function anyways. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO payments_facebook(`adset`,`amount`,`date`,`oid` ) VALUES 
('6023516764849','3.27','2015-07-25','58'),
('6023315002249','200','2015-07-25','53'),
('6023221698649','3.43','2015-07-25','52')";
```

Comment: Hello Mathieu, This answer is the correct and worked. it is a good workaround for the limitations of mysql_query(). Thank you for your response.